# Nginx+uWSGi+Django long task Bad Gateway error

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a long task in one of my django's views that take 120-200 seconds to generate the response.

For this particular view, Nginx raises `502 Bad Gateway` after 1 minute with this error message in the logs:

```
[error] 7719#7719: *33 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream,
```

here are my Nginx configurations:

```
upstream DjangoServer {
    server      127.0.0.1:8000;
    keepalive   300;
}
location / {
    include             proxy_params;
    proxy_pass          http://DjangoServer;
    allow               all;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_set_header    X-Cluster-Client-Ip $remote_addr;

    client_max_body_size    20M;
    keepalive_timeout       300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_send_timeout      300;
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    send_timeout            300;
}
```

And here are my uWSGI Configurations:

```
uid=www-data
gid=www-data
http=127.0.0.1:8000
http-keepalive=300
master=1
vacuum=1
workers=2
threads=5
log-5xx=1
```

Note:

- The Nginx and uWSGI work fine for all other views.
- Django development server can run the task with no problem.
- After the Nginx 502 error, uWSGI keeps running in the background and completes the job, (according to in view print statements).
- If I try to connect to uWSGI via the browser, after a while (less than 120s) it will say `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

You can assume the task like this

```py
def long_task_view(request):
    start_time = time.time()
    print(start_time)
    # doing stuff
    time.sleep(130)
    print(time.time() - start_time)
    return HttpResponse("The result")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try increase the time out time of nginx:

```
vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Add this in http:

```
http {
     ...
     fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
     ...
}
```

But the best practice is to create an asynchronous process to process the method that takes. I usually celery for async task.

Comment: This not solve my problem, thanks for suggesting celery.

Comment: I would try do process in assync, if possible